# Laravel replace/convert @foreach loop to vue v-for loop with database relationship

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Im making a laravel SPA and I recently learned how to use vue and I know how `v-for` works for vue using my components. I only know how to loop only in a single table without relation thats why I'm having a difficult time changing it. I have two tables which are `news` and `comments`, and this table `news` hasMany `comments` in it.

my blade file for now.

```
@foreach($news->comments as $comment)
<div class="comment" style="background-color: #f6efef;" >
<div class="author-info">
  <img src={{"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5(strtolower(trim($comment->email))) . "?s=50&d=retro" }} class="author-image" id="image">
  <div class="author-name">
       <h4>{{$comment->name}} </h4>
       <p class="author-time"> {{  date('jS F, Y - g:iA' ,strtotime($comment->created_at)) }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comment-content">
        {{$comment->comment}}
</div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

```
your component goes like this in vue2.0

**block.vue**

<template>
 <div class="comment" style="background-color: #f6efef;" v-for="comment in 
   news.comments" >
   <div class="author-info">
      <img :src="comment.author_image" }} class="author-image" id="image">
      <div class="author-name">
       <h4>{{ comment.name }} </h4>
       <p class="author-time"> {{ comment.time }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="comment-content">
        {{ comment.comment }}
   </div>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
   name: "block",
   props: [ "news" ], //or
   data() => ({ news: [] })
}
</script>
```

Comment: So I should only call the `news` table and put it in the `data` object in my script sir? How about the comments? No need to put in a `data` object? Im a bit confused.

Comment: you can get news along with comments from controller using relation. syntax will be like `News::with('comments') ->toArray();`